# receiving list of values by POST Method using ASP.NET Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post, asp.net-core

I couldn't find any way to do this. The example of my code is here.

First the **View**

```
<form id="listForm" action="Index" method="post">
<ul>
@foreach (loop condition) {
    <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="@item.val1" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="val2" value="@item.val2" />
        ...other items...
    </li>
}
</ul>
</form>
<a id="button"></a>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function(e){
            $("#listForm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index([FromForm]ValueModel value)
{
    return Content(value.val1);
}
```

(at here I only receive first data set, e.g. `val1: "1", val2: "str1"`)

And the **Model**

```
public class ValueModel
{
    public string val1 { get; set; }
    public string val2 { get; set; }
}
```

(Why I make process like this is I change `val1` and `val2` in View using JavaScript and I need this datas in another View page.)

The point is that

I have list of data 
(for example, the request body is like

```
val1: "1"
val1: "2"
val2: "str1"
val2: "str2"
```

`val1: "1", val2: "str2"` is first data set and `val1: "2", val2: "str2"` is second data set
)

and I need to receive this in Controller (I can only receive `val1: "1" and val2: "str1"` since I make parameter of Controller `[FromForm]ValueModel value`)

I need really serious.. please help.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

<ul>
@foreach (loop condition) {
  <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="@item.val1" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="val2" value="@item.val2" />
      ...other items...
 </li>
}
</ul>

@Html.ActionLink("Submit", "", null, new { @id = "submit" })

}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
         document.forms[0].submit();
         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Check the full code here, i have used action link you can use button also

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ValueModel person)
{
return Content(value.val1);
}
```

Hope you got the correction